# Merging cells horizontally across twelve columns

Tags: sql, merge, report, builder, cells

I am trying to merge cells horizontally, and I understand it can't be done dynamically by expression, so I'm looking for suggestions on a possible alternative way to accomplish it.  I have 3 columns of data and then the next 12 columns are months.  They enter the start month and then it's a rolling twelve month display.  The user want's the top row of the heading to be the year, but merged.  The second row of the heading is the month name.  I've suggested to the user the easy task of merging after the export, but she also wants it exported to PPT and be ready to publish without modification.  Any ideas?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6Aum.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like pretty simple stuff to you veterans, but I'm new to SQL and SSRS.  So, to answer my own question, I ended up creating 12 rows that I can make visible according to the starting month of the rolling 12 months.  I wasn't sure how that would work, but it is working great and I now have a foundation if I ever need it again.